# CORRECTED AND WORKING - calling d3 zoom behaviour manually does not carry out the zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have a radar that I can zoom into, this all works if I am scrolling in with the mouse or pinch zooming. However, when i double click on an arc within the radar it needs to zoom in to it. 
i have removed the default double click  with

```
.on('dblclick.zoom',null);
```

and I have a double click event on each arc that can be double clicked (so it is not going through the zoom listener). This double click handler calls the zoom listeners scale and translate functions and then the event. I have tried calling the scale then event and then the translate and then the event but I get the same result, nothing zooms

```
 RadarDraw.ZoomListener.scale(6);
 RadarDraw.ZoomListener.translate([0, 0]);
 RadarDraw.ZoomListener.event(svg.transition().duration(500));
```

from what I have read this should work. Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks 
Mark

my zoom handler function looks like this

```
function zoom(){
    if (d3.event.scale <= 1 || d3.event.scale > 5) {
            //on scale 1 (zoomed out) center the radar to its origianl position

            //if (RadarDraw.ZoomListener.scale() <= 1 && previousZoom)
            //{
            //    resetZoomOut();
            //    previousZoom = false;
            //}

            var scalesize;
            if (d3.event.scale <= 1)
            {
                scalesize = 1;
            }
            if (d3.event.scale > 5)
            {
                scalesize = 0.2;
            }

            $(".isadot").each(function (i, v) {
                var tmp = v;
                var PrevTransform = tmp.attributes["transform"].nodeValue;

                //copy translate only remove other scale
                var currentTrans = PrevTransform.split(" ");

                tmp.attributes["transform"].nodeValue = currentTrans[0] + " scale(" + scalesize + ")";
            });

            previousZoomLevel = d3.event.scale;

            return;
        } else {
           // RadarDraw.ZoomListener.translate(d3.event.translate);

            //allow panning not zoom between min and max
            svg.attr("transform", "translate("
            + (d3.event.translate[0] + (_config.Width / 2)) + "," + (d3.event.translate[1] + (_config.Height / 2))
            + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");

            if (d3.event.scale > 1)
                previousZoom = true;

            //if we are zoomed in and out previous zoom level is 5 or above then exit zoom (we are either scrolling out or pinching out of zoom)
            if (tools.IsArcFocused && previousZoomLevel >= 5) {
                tools.ExitZoom(false);
            }

            //scale the dots by the zom level
            var scalesize = 0.6;
            //switch (RadarDraw.ZoomListener.scale())
            //{
            //    case ():
            //        break;
            //    default:
            //        scalesize = 0.6;
            //        break;
            //}

            if (d3.event.scale <= 1) {
                scalesize = 1;
            }
            if (d3.event.scale >= 5) {
                scalesize = 0.4;
            }

            $(".isadot").each(function (i, v) {
                var tmp = v;
                var PrevTransform = tmp.attributes["transform"].nodeValue;

                //copy translate only remove other scale
                var currentTrans = PrevTransform.split(" ");

                tmp.attributes["transform"].nodeValue = currentTrans[0] + " scale(" + scalesize + ")";
            });

        }
}
```

**EDIT**

Rob was correct it ended up being .on('dblclick.zoom',null); that was causing the issue in ie 9, after commenting it out it acted as expected. Thanks for the back and forth Rob, got there in the end haha.

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle.net?  Here's a template, just add your code to it, the libraries are already included. http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/5nHGz/3/

Comment: I cant add the rest of the code or even split it out to something simple unfortunatly. Any other way how i could explain it better for you?

Comment: I hate flying blind with something this tricky, so I won't give any concrete recommendations as it probably just ends up wasting both of our time!  Have a look how I implement my zoom listener here http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/
I'm not sure those methods you are using are valid i.e. `RadarDraw.ZoomListener.scale(6);` etc.

Comment: having a look through that now. the RadarDraw.ZoomListener is just set as follows RadarDraw.ZoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 5]).on("zoom", zoom);

Comment: Sorry I'm talking absolute bollo**s, I see I am calling the `zoomListener` in the same way, line38/39 of my code. . . .

Comment: Why can you not share your code or just make a simple example?

Comment: I cannot due to work not letting me. The graph it is implemented on is a radar (not like the d3 example one) that is made of a number of arcs dependant on the data being fed into it and then dots are positioned into the various arcs in. maybe i can have just a single svg with the same zoom code, would that work as an example?

Comment: I was going to say lets go to chat about this but then my work firewall does not allow it

Comment: Good grief, your work surely are restrictive!  Yes perhaps as `close` to your scenario (totally sanitised) of course would certainly help!

Comment: yeah they are its a pain sometimes cannot even see google groups. I made a js fiddle using the the calls i am using but with just a simple cricle (although its basically constructed the sameway as the the circle is in a svg container, like what i call in my code). The zooms like right away so im not sure could it be that another process is blocking the zoom / translate?

Comment: Quite possibly your `.on('dblclick.zoom',null);` is interfering but I'm really just guessing :( - Proxy servers or VPN's are great for getting round those over-restrictive firewalls!

Comment: i have noticed that in my zoom handler function if i use d3.event.scale isntead of radardraw.zoomlistener.scale it zooms in, but leaving this then causes a different issue of the dots being translated to 0,0, could it being that radardraw.zoomlistener is being reset or something

Comment: Sorry Mark, this is getting too tedious.

Comment: yeah its ok, im feeling the same way :P

Comment: Hi rob, In chrome this is now working but in IE 9 it is not, is there any known issue with ie 9?Cheers

Comment: Mark, ***what*** is now working?! As mentioned this is too tedious right now to *guess*.  I amongst many are likely available for real `NDA`consulting, since your company has heavy resources for security, they won't mind surely on a bit of consultancy!

Comment: Its fine if you see the edit in the post i sorted it. You pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks